# The hash values of unity asset bundles generated by different computers are different

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The hash values of asset bundles generated by different computers (same system version) and unity (same version of unity,unity2020.3.19) are different.Is there any good solution?

Calculating hash using asset bundle is different, and calculating hash using generated manifest is also different.

Comment: Fun fact: If you have different line endings for assets and meta files the hash will be different even though the content of the files is otherwise identical. Always force it to linefeed only in your source control if that option is available. We spent a long time figuring that out and now our hashes are identical on every computer and operating system we use.

Comment: This may help too: https://forum.unity.com/threads/about-incremental-build-and-asset-bundle-hashes.1436032/